# cannot save Boolean value using onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, restore

I want to save Boolean variable using `onSaveInstanceState` so the value will be changed when I come back to the Activity.
for some reason it doesn't happen. This is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
....
public boolean appLanched=true;

//switch to PassActivity
private void toPW() {
Intent intentToPW = new Intent(this, PassActivity.class);
startActivity(intentToPW);
}
    ....
//back in MainActivity
        @Override
     protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     //variable to change state to "false"
     outState.putBoolean("appLanched", false);
    }
  @Override
     protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
     appLanched=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("appLanched");
                      }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//adding this   
 if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        appLanched=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("appLanched");
    } 
 //only if `true` switch Activity  
            if(appLanched) {
        toPW();
    }
    ...
```

running and debugging it I see that instead of switch back to MainActivity it is immediately going back again to the PassActivity and also that it doesn't execute `onRestoreInstanceState` method.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the SharedPreferences Android provides.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thanks, but why SharedPreferences? any reason savedInstanceState is not the correct way?

Comment: I was thinking that `SharedPreferences` might work better because you can call the values anytime and they persist even after app is "destroyed"  (Maybe the Bundle state persists also? I never use it.) But in any case, the android docs show that the super is called after the values are set `outState.putBoolean("appLanched", false); super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`

Comment: @Barns Thanks! took your advice with `SharedPreferences`.